# How can i make a code in R that opens a .csv file outside the Rstudio

Tags: r, windows, system-calls

The code scrapes from the two websites, turns them into a data frame and then into a csv file and that file is located at C:/Users/JoséLuiz/Desktop/news. What i want is to make a code that opens those csv files so they can pop up at my screen and "tell me" that there is some new refreshed data over there so i don't have to close and open the files every single time. I was trying to make a windows forms with .net framework but it got really complicated.

```
    library(rvest)
    library(xml2)
    library(WriteXLS)

    setwd("C:/Users/JoséLuiz")
    setwd("C:/Users/JoséLuiz/Desktop/news")
    while(TRUE){
      ###Broadcast
      time <- Sys.time()
      hora <- format(time, '%H')
      minuto <- format(time, '%M')
      segundo <- format(time, '%S')
      url <- 'http://broadcast.com.br/'
      html <- read_html(url)
      headlines <- html %>%
      html_nodes('.materia :nth-child(1) a')%>%
       html_text()
      write.table(headlines, file = "Headlines.csv", row.names = F, sep = ',')
      #Trading ecconomics
      url <- 'https://www.investing.com/news/economic-indicators'
      endereco <- read_html(url)
      manchete <- endereco %>%
      html_nodes('.title')%>%
        html_text()
      details <- endereco %>%
       html_nodes('p')%>%
    html_text()
      time <- endereco %>%
        html_nodes('.date')%>%
        html_text()
      manchete <- data.frame(manchete)
      write.table(manchete,file = "Manchetes_Trading_Ecconomics.csv", row.names = F, sep = ',')
      setwd("C:/Users/JoséLuiz/Desktop/news")

      Sys.sleep(300)
    }
```

Comment: Add this line before `Sys.sleep(300)`: `shell("Manchetes_Trading_Ecconomics.csv", wait = FALSE); shell("Headlines.csv", wait = FALSE)`. Then these files will be opened in your default program for CSV files.

Comment: It worked!!! thanks a lot bro! Very glad you commented here. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

You can open the csv, check the dimensions/number of rows and compare it to the file you are saving to see if there is new r refreshed data. Something like the following should do the trick.

```
# Add this at the beginning (outside your while loop

tmp = rio::import("Manchetes_Trading_Ecconomics.csv")    

# Add this after the line manchete <- data.frame(manchete)

if(dim(df)[1] != dim(df2)[1]){
    print("New data added") } else{
    print("No new data added") }
```